# PySide6(Qt 6.0+) QPSQL driver not loaded

Tags: python, postgresql, psql, pyside6

I wrote the project in Windows 10. I use the Postgres database. I use QSqlTableModel to display the client table.

```
self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)
```

Now changed the device to macbook m1 (macOS Monterey). And the problems began. Psycopg2-binary installed. I connect to the database. But the QSqlTableModel doesn't work. When starting a project, the following errors appear on the PyCharm:

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL
QSqlDatabase: an instance of QCoreApplication is required for loading driver plugins
```

The terminal shows the following:

```
marcus@MacBook-Air-Marcus ~ % postgres -V                     
postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.2
marcus@MacBook-Air-Marcus ~ % psql -V    
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.2
```

Link I created.

```
marcus@MacBook-Air-Marcus ~ % brew link --overwrite postgresql
Linking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql/14.2_1... 4318 symlinks created.

marcus@MacBook-Air-Marcus bin % export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/14.2/bin
marcus@MacBook-Air-Marcus bin % export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib  
marcus@MacBook-Air-Marcus bin % echo $PATH          
/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/14.2/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib
```

I can't figure out how to fix them.

UPDATE
In PATH, the path to the qmake file (/Users/marcus/Qt/6.3.0/macos/bin) added.

```
marcus@MacBook-Air-Marcus sqldrivers % echo $PATH
/Users/marcus/Qt/6.3.0/macos/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/marcus/Qt/6.3.0/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
```

The following method is specified in the documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qpsql):
How to Build the QPSQL Plugin on Unix and macOS
You need the PostgreSQL client library and headers installed.

To make qmake find the PostgreSQL header files and shared libraries, run qmake the following way (assuming that the PostgreSQL client is installed in /usr):

```
cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
qmake -- PSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/pgsql
make sub-psql
```

But I can't do it. Excuse me. I'm new to that.

```
marcus@MacBook-Air-Marcus psql % pwd
/Users/marcus/Qt/6.3.0/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql
marcus@MacBook-Air-Marcus psql % qmake -o Makefile /Users/marcus
Cannot read /Users/marcus: file to open is a directory
```

The following files are available in the directory

```
marcus@MacBook-Air-Marcus psql % ls
CMakeLists.txt  main.cpp    qsql_psql.cpp
README      psql.json   qsql_psql_p.h
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Do you have qsqlpsql plugin?

Comment: I don't have this plugin. Windows was simple. Installed the driver through an exe file, copied the necessary dll to the project directory and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

QPSQL is just a wrapper to libpq library. you must install either Postgres application on your machine either with brew or downloading and installing Postgres.app
Then make your application aware where the library is:
for example if you used brew set environment variable

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/brew/lib
```

In case of Postgres.app find the lib path in the content of Postgres.app